# arm template, customscriptextension is failing with returned a non-zero exit code of: '1'. Command execution may have been interrupted by a VM restart

Tags: azure-rm-template

i have a arm template that contains a customscriptextension that is meant to install an app (Sophos AV and Notepad++) from a storage account.
the deployment is picking up the storageaccount correctly and copying the sophos.ps1 file from the blob storage account and adding it to the VM.

i can find the file in this location

**C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Downloads\0**

the log file for the customscriptextension shows that sophos file is downloaded.

```
[INFO] DownloadFiles: fileUri = https://stgacctname.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/sophos.ps1

[INFO] DownloadFiles: fileDownloadPath = C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.12\Downloads\0

[INFO] Waiting for all async file download tasks to complete...

[INFO] DownloadFiles: asynchronously downloaded file to fileDownloadLocation = Downloads\0\sophos.ps1

[INFO] Files downloaded. Asynchronously executing command: 'SecureCommand_0'

[INFO] Command execution task started. Awaiting completion...
```

but the install of this file is failing and spitting out this error

```
**[ERROR] Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a non-zero exit code of: '1'. Command execution may have been interrupted by a VM restart**


[INFO] {"sequenceNumber":0,"totalDuration":21317,"status":"error","code":1,"filesDownloaded":1,"durationOfFileDownload":336,"durationOfDownloadHashing":0,"statusFileAccessed":5,"operation":"enable","operationDuration":123,"operationResult":"success","operationSizeOfOutput":42,"operationSizeOfError":0,"sha256HashOfCommandToExecute":"HASHNUMBER","downloadSummary":{"downloadUris":["https://stgacctname.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/sophos.ps1"],"fileHashes":[{"fileName":"sophos.ps1","sha256Hash":"HASHNUMBER"}]}}
```

the sophos.ps1 file contains the following

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass
cmdkey /add:stgacctname.file.core.windows.net /user:AZURE\stgacctname /pass:sttgacctkey
    \\stgacctname.file.core.windows.net\fileshare\SophosSetup.exe --quiet --devicegroup="Test servers"
    \\stgacctname.file.core.windows.net\fileshare\npp.8.1.4.Installer.x64.exe /S
```

when i open the PS1 file and run it as admin it runs and installs sophos without any issues.

so question is...why is it failing here?
my thoughts are that the PS1 file is not being run as admin... its running as a standard user so its failing.. but thats just pure speculation.

can anybody shed some light on what could be happening?
let me know if you need any more info...

in the mean time i will keep digging around....

cheers!

Comment: i added Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass to the sophos.ps1 script and that resolved part of the issue....
Notepad++ installed but Sophos did not.... pretty sure its some sort of permissions/UAC issue. I cannot find any logs or info as to why its not installing.. nothing in event viewer either...

Comment: think we found it... Firewall stopping sophos from downloading its stuff from sophos itself...